# How can I use the end of an css animation when the button is active

Tags: css

I have a css animation on my button :

[gif_demo_css_animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7FlD.gif)

```css
.btn_nav {
    color: black;
}

.btn_nav::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -3px; /* Réglez la position de la ligne selon vos besoins */
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px; /* Épaisseur de la ligne */
    background-color: #689351; /* Couleur de la ligne */
    transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Transition pour une animation fluide */
    opacity: 0; /* Initialement invisible */
}


.btn_nav:hover::after {
    bottom: -1px; /* Position de la ligne lors du survol */
    opacity: 1; /* Rend la ligne visible */
}
```

```html
<button class='btn_nav'>button</button>
```

I want this result to be display when I put the button as active, I wonder if it's possible to get the exact same result? I tried to reuse this css but it colors the background of the button. I also tried to use border-bottom but it doesn't align the same way.

Comment: The shown code does not appear to reproduce what your screenshot shows, at all. Provide a _proper_ [mre] first of all, please.

Comment: Do you mean to use box-shadow with inset?

Answer (score 1):

Using `<button>` elements instead of links for a user menu is not very
common, but, yes, it's possible to make them look like links.

By default, buttons, like other form elements, will use the system font
family and size. This is why we usually use `<a>` tags inside `<ul>`
and `<li>` tags, all that wrapped inside a `<nav>` tag.

But you can make a `<button>` look like a link, if you remove its
border and background. You'll also have to override the default font
settings, but this can be done by inheriting from the `<html>` or
`<body>` font settings.

I put your two buttons inside a `<nav>` tag and displayed them next to
each other by simply using
[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
with a little gap.

Playing with the good units is also quite important. I prefer not using
`px` as it is not elastic. If someone changes the font size, then the `em`
unit will be much easier to use. If you increase or decrease the font
size, then all your paddings and spacings will grow or reduce with it,
making it look "normal" and not unbalanced.

I've added a few comments in your CSS, keeping them in French, for you.

```css
html {
  /* Pour ressembler à ton GIF animé. */
  font: 20px/1.4 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.user-menu {
  display: flex; /* Côte à côte, par défaut en row. */
  gap: .5em; /* Rajouter un petit espace entre les boutons. */
}

.btn_nav {
  position: relative; /* Parce que l'élément ::after est en absolute. */
  font: inherit; /* Pour ne pas hériter du bouton de l'OS. */
  color: black;
  background: none; /* Enlever le fond gris du bouton. */
  border: none; /* Enlever les bordures du bouton. */
  padding: .4em 1em; /* Un peu d'espace autour. */
  cursor: pointer; /* Changer le curseur de la souris en main. */
}

.btn_nav::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; /* Relatif à .btn_nav */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -.1em; /* Position de la ligne légèrement en-dessous du bas du bouton. */
  height: 2px; /* Épaisseur de la ligne. */
  background-color: #689351; /* Couleur de la ligne. */
  transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Transition pour une animation fluide. */
  opacity: 0; /* Initialement invisible. */
}


/* Lors du survol sur le bouton. */
.btn_nav:hover::after {
  bottom: 0; /* Remonter la ligne à raz le bas du bouton. (voir padding). */
  opacity: 1; /* Rend la ligne visible. */
}
```

```html
<nav class="user-menu">
  <button class="btn_nav">S'inscrire</button>
  <button class="btn_nav">Se connecter</button>
</nav>
```